# Update time descriptions every minute using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, unix-timestamp

I have created the following code to update the text contents of all spans like this every minute. There are numerous of these spans on the page which all need to be updated every minute:

```
<span data-unix="1372263005" class="time_ago">4 minutes ago</span>
```

The code is as follows:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    $(".time_ago").each(function(i, elem) { 
        var unix = $(elem).attr("data-unix")
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        now = parseInt(now) / 1000;
        var amount = 0;
        var difference = 0;

        difference = parseInt(now) - parseInt(unix);

        if (difference < 60)
        {
            $(elem).html('a few seconds ago');
        }
        else if (difference < 120)
        {
            $(elem).html('a minute ago');
        }
        else if (difference < 3600)
        {
            amount = Math.floor(difference / 60);
            $(elem).html(amount + ' minutes ago');
        }
        else if (difference < 7200)
        {
            $(elem).html('an hour ago');
        }
        else if (difference < 86400)
        {
            amount = Math.floor(difference / 3600);
            $(elem).html(amount + ' hours ago');
        }
        else if (difference < 172800)
        {
            $(elem).html('a day ago');
        }
        else if (difference < 2635200)
        {
            amount = Math.floor(difference / 86400);
            $(elem).html(amount + ' days ago');
        }
        else if (difference < 5270400)
        {
            $(elem).html('a month ago');
        }
        else if (difference < 31622400)
        {
            amount = Math.floor(difference / 2635200);
            $(elem).html(amount + ' months ago');
        }
        else if (difference < 63244800)
        {
            $(elem).html('a year ago');
        }
        else
        {
            amount = Math.floor(difference / 31622400);
            $(elem).html(amount + ' years ago');
        }
    });
    return false;
}, 60);
```

EDIT1) Ok, now I have made some changes on your advice but it's changing the span texts to 43351 years. Any ideas why it is doing that?

EDIT2) Ok, now I have /1000 so that the php unix time matches with the js getTime(). The only problem is that now it is applying this to all the values. ie) I get 31 minutes for all the instances of .time_ago - how do I get it to apply only to one at a time so I get different times for each instance?

EDIT3) Added correct code in case anyone finds it useful..

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a global `floor()` method, but it does have `Math.floor()`.

Comment: Also, your `else` shouldn't have a condition after it. `else (difference >= 63244800)`

Comment: Also, you're using `.text()` to set HTML content, which will cause the full HTML syntax to be displayed instead of parsed.

Comment: Also, `unix` isn't a valid attribute name. You should use something like `data-unix` to at least be HTML5 compliant.

Comment: Also, `$(".time_ago").text();` won't give you the number you want for the time comparison. You should be getting your `unix` attribute, or `data-unix` if you fixed it.

Comment: I see you've run down my checklist. Only other thing I see is that you seem to be assuming your comparison numbers, like `60`, `120`, etc., represent seconds, when in fact they're milliseconds. You'll need to multiply them by `1000`, like `60000`, `120000`, etc.

Comment: ohhhhh new Date().getTime() returns miliseconds then? This I did not know! ty lets test...

Comment: Ok this works but unfortunately it is applying the same time measure to all instances of .time_ago - how do I get it to show different times for each one?

Comment: Wrap all that code in the `setInterval` in `.each()`, as in `$(".timeago").each(function(i, elem) { var unix = $(elem).attr("data-unix") /* and so on */ });` The `elem` parameter in the callback represents the current `.time_ago` element in the iteration. That's why you do `$(elem).attr(...` and so you'll also do `$(elem).text(...`.

Comment: it works!!! it works!! ty so much I really learned a lot from this crazy!! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`floor()` is a function on the `Math` object, so to call it you'll need to use `Math.floor()`.

You might consider setting a message in each of your if/else blocks and setting it once at the end of your function. That way if you need to change any classes or attributes, you'll only need to do it in one place.

A few other notes: use html() instead of text() set HTML content; you should use a radix when using [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), otherwise anything with a leading 0 will be parsed as an octal number, not decimal.

You'll want to set the `unix` attribute using the HTML5 convention of starting with `data-`, then you can either use jQuery's `data()` or `attr()` function to retrieve the value. If you use the `data()` function, jQuery will cast the value to an integer for you.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    var unix = $(".time_ago").data('unix');
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var amount = 0;
    var difference = now - unix;
    var message = "";

    if (difference < 60)
    {
        message = 'a few seconds ago';
    }
    else if (difference < 120) {
        message = 'a minute ago';
    }
    ...

    //just do this once
    $(".time_ago").html('<span data-unix="' + unix + '" class="time_ago">' + message + '</span>');
    return false;
}, 60);
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got this error because *floor()* is not a function in JS.

Each time you use

```
floor()
```

use

```
Math.floor()
```

instead.